# Why an integral does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to construct a counter example of Fubini Thorem, and for that we need a function $f$ in the product space which is not absolute integrable.

So, let $f:[1,\infty)\times{[0,1]}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ given by $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}$. Then I know $f$ is not integrable on $[1,\infty)\times{[0,1]}$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x,y) \ge \begin{cases} e^{-1}, &\text{if } y\le 1/x, \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}; \end{cases}
$$
Since the set $\{ x\ge1,\, 0\le y\le1/x\}$ has infinite measure, the right-hand side is not integrable, hence neither is the left-hand side.